# ScrolltoPage or element on Page Load, iscroll4

Tags: scrollto, pageload, iscroll4

So the scrolltopage or element or position are pretty straightforward.
But does anyone know how to get this to work automatically on page load?

I've tried adding a :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#start2").trigger('click');
    });
```

to link to the scrolltopage div, to no success.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind got it
added

```
        <body
        onload="myScroll.scrollToElement('li:nth-child(3)', 0)" ;="">
```

with this in the html

```
       <div id="start2" onclick="myScroll.scrollToElement('li:nth-child(3)', 0);"/>
```

now anyone think it's possible to add an anchor to this so that the position changes dependent on the previous page?